# Using an interface type with compareTo() - error (java)

Tags: java, oop, interface

Here is my Item class, which implements Thing (my interface)

```
package moving.domain;

public class Item implements Thing, Comparable<Thing>{

private int volume;
private String name;

public Item (String name, int vol) {

    this.name = name;
    this.volume = vol;
}

public String getName() {

    return this.name;
}

@Override
public int getVolume() {

    return this.volume;
}

 @Override
public String toString() {

    return this.getName() + " (" + this.getVolume() + " dm^3)";
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Thing t) {
    return (int) Integer.compare(this.getVolume(),(t.getVolume())); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Here is the interface

```
package moving.domain;

public interface Thing {

    int getVolume();               

}
```

and here is the main method

```
package moving;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import moving.domain.Item;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import moving.domain.Thing;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // test your program here
        Map<String, Thing> items2 = new HashMap<String, Thing>();
        //storing interface type Thing in hashmap as value      

        items2.put("three", new Item("passport", 2));
        items2.put("two", new Item("toothbrash", 1));
        items2.put("one", new Item("circular saw", 100));
        List<Thing> items3 = new ArrayList<Thing>(items2.values());

        Collections.sort(items3);
        //
        System.out.println(items3);

    }
}
```

When I try to sort the collection I get the following error:

```
no suitable method found for sort(List<Thing>)

method Collections <T#1>sort<List<T#1>) is not applicable

(inferred type does not conform to upper bounds(s)

inferred: Thing

upper bounds(s) Comparable <? super Thing>)

method Collections<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<?superT#2>)is not applicable

(cannot infer type - variables T#2

(actual and formal argument lengths differ in length)

where T#1,T#2 are type variables:

T#1 extends comparable <?super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)

t#2 extends object declared in method <t#2>sort(List<t#2>, Comparator<?super t#2>)
```

I got the same error when I tried to create the same program as shown in section 45 of the following: https://materiaalit.github.io/2013-oo-programming/part2/week-9/

I then recreated the same situation in the above code to see if it happened again and it did. It's really bugging me and I can't seem to understand what the problem is. In the end I even copied and pasted all of the code from section 45 and it still gave the same error, and it gives it here. Can interface types be sorted using an interface reference? Am I missing something obvious? If I change all the type declarations to Item it works.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // test your program here
      List<Thing> items = new ArrayList<Thing>();
items.add(new Item("passport", 2));
items.add(new Item("toothbrash", 1));
items.add(new Item("circular saw", 100));

Collections.sort(items);
System.out.println(items);

}
```

I get the same error when I create an ArrayList of things, as above.

Comment: Your `Thing` interface should extend `Comparable<Thing>` remove `implements Comparable<Thing>` from `Item` class and just implement `Thing` in `Item` class - your concrete class will be forced to implement both methods, and the `Collections.sort()` will now work.

Answer (score 1):

Your error occurs because `Thing`s are not necessarily `Comparable`.  The only class you've made implements both `Thing` and `Comparable<Thing>`, but you could easily create:

```
public class UncomparableThing implements Thing {  /* ... */ }
```

It's not `Comparable`.  It illustrates the possibility that the compiler sees when you attempt to sort a `List<Thing>`.  `Thing`s aren't necessarily `Comparable`.

You could change the list to a `List<Item>` if you want, because you've defined `Item`s to be `Comparable`.  Alternatively, you could have the `Thing` interface extend `Comparable<Thing>`.  Another option is to pass a `Comparator<Thing>` as a second argument to `Collections.sort`, as a way to compare objects that aren't `Comparable`.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. That's made things a lot clearer for me.